# Create pandas column based on condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas

This expression

```
df["column"].diff() != 0
```

Gives me a pandas series of booleans. I now would like a column `df["result"]` where there's the value `100` for every True value in `df["column"]` and `0` for every False.

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
df["result"] = 100 if df["column"].diff() != 0 else 0
```

I understand I'd have to use loc, but from this:

```
df.loc[df["column"].diff() != 0]
```

How do I then set the result column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is best use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set 2 values by condition, solution is vectorized:

```
df["result"] = np.where(df["column"].diff() != 0, 100, 0)
```

Your code:

```
df["result"] = 100 if df["column"].diff() != 0 else 0
```

not working, because here are used 1d arrays, (Series) so cannot be used scalar solution.

You also get:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

And it means there is no clear, what is scalar output from array of boolean from `df["column"].diff() != 0`.

More information is in [Using if/truth statements with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for something like this:

```
df.loc[df['column'].diff()!=0, 'Result'] = 100
```

Edit after jezrael's comment:

```
df['diff'] = df['column'].diff().fillna(0)
df.loc[df['diff'] != 0, 'Result'] = 100
```

Comment: get `NaN`s instaed 0, so if want use this solution, first need set `0` to column

Comment: I think he meant the result column would need to be set to 0 first. Thanks for your input!